# Angular, provider across multiple modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a provider to kind of try and play around with my own set of "state" saving. I have a provider set up in it's own module and injects into 2 separate "child modules" of the app I want to use it on. Each of them has a config set up where they send some information I would like to hold onto. The issue I am having right now is it does not seem to be holding the info as I was thinking it would. I basically want to create one big object in a provider, each module would contribute with it'd own config. Let me show what I mean.

The provider looks like so -

```
  angular.
module('urlTesting.testProvider', [])
.provider("freshUrl", function(){

    //our state object
    var currentState = {};

    return {
        stateName : function(name){
            //test function
            this.state_name = name;
        },
        addState :  function(modName, item, variables){
            var newState = { "module" : modName, "customUrl" : [{ "name" : item, "options" : variables}]};
            _.extend(currentState, newState);
            console.log(currentState, modName);
        },
        $get: function(){
            return {
                state: currentState
            };
        }
    }
});
```

And a config in a different module looks like so :

```
.config(function(freshUrlProvider){
    //module name, state name, provided state variables
    freshUrlProvider.addState("module1", "mod1", ["true", "false"]);
});
```

So I have 2 modules, both doing this, the only difference is the items in module 2 are names module2 and mod2.

So I have click functions controllers in each module that call the provider and as for the currentState (see the $get)

So they just do a :

```
 console.log(freshUrl.state);
```

Now, where I am having a problem is - in module 1 when I click this I get back only the object for module 2 ( { "module": "module2 ...ect ), and when I click that in module 2, I get back undefined.

My thinking was the _.extend would combine all these objects into currentState, but it does not seem to be working how I thought. Could use some help as I seem to have hit a wall. Thanks for reading!

The underlying idea is (like routes) the modules would separately set their configs so I could use them upfront -- so I would like all the config objects being sent to be combined into one big currentState object, hence _.extend.

Edit : Maybe this is a job for a modularized factory, not a provider? I just thought it would be nice to let each module set its custom params in the config - but I can't seen to get this to create and use one big object across all modules.

Edit2: I found this article (http://garabagne.io/2014/06/08/the-life-and-times-of-the-angular-provider/) which was a pretty great read on providers, however I am still unsure if this is how I should approach this problem.

I think i've honed it down to the question - can you use the same provider across multiple modules (in module fashion) to have 1 place that will keep track of all config vars. It seems like the answer to this would be no, as they are considered singletons.

Comment: This is not to fix the problem, but an idea: since they are unique, have you considered using an object structure like `currentState.module2.mod2 = ["true", "false"]`?

Comment: @Shomz Ah, yes I definitely need to restructure the object I am working with because I will need to do checks (if mod1 exists for example), that is a great idea.

Comment: In that case you won't have to deal with `_extend` and it should all just work. :)